# UILocalNotification expires?

Tags: uilocalnotification, lifetime, period

I have an App based on `UILocalNotifications`. By documentation, if notification for some reason hasn't been fired (for example iphone was off), then it should fire immediately as iphone is turned on. In my case it has not fired. I had my phone turned off for one day 
and when I've turned it on, notification hasn't fired at all.

So I would like to know if `UILocalNotification` has some special lifetime, after which it will not expires.